# what's wrong with this javascript regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to find instances of "N/A" in markup and swap out with something else,

```
var $reg = new RegExp('[Nn]/[Aa]');
```

other variations were:

- `/[Nn]/[Aa]/`
- `'^[Nn]/[Aa]'`

Comment: You just need to escape that forward slash. Turn `/` into `\/`

Comment: And how do you _apply_ that regex? What is the actual outcome and the expected outcome?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
stringToSearchIn.replace(/(N\/A)/gi,'words to replace with');
```

1. `\/` escapes the slash, as the `/` character delimits the regex string, and
2. the `gi` at the end:

   - `g` is for a global search, so it doesn't stop after the first match, and
   - `i` is case-insensitive (so it'll match `n` and `N`, `a` and `A`.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A74FB/)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use this one:

```
N\/A
```